# multiple isotope layout issue

Tags: jquery, layout

Hi I am new to Jquery so I need help with Isotope. I am using two Isotope content filters on the same page.

the url is

```
    http://176.9.5.243/~marin/offers.html
```

The isotope in tab SHOP works fine but the problem happens with the tab TRAVEL.

I would be really grateful for any kind of help.

Aleksandar

Comment: I cant see the problem which browser you are viewing on?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely zou will see. On page load the shops tab is open and isotope looks okay. If you open TRAVEL tab - the isotope layout is messed up. The items are not lined up in a grid but in a stack. That is the problem. It is visible on Chrome and on a FF also so it is not a css issue. Or I think it's not...